# Populating a list of tuples in a semantic way

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm working on a piece of code where I have to process lists of tuples where both the order and names of the "keys" (`fst`s of the tuples) match a certain template. I'm implementing fault tolerance by validating and (if needed) generating a valid list based on the input.

Here's an example of what I mean:

Given the template of keys, `["hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "test"]`, and a list `[("hello", Just 1), ("world", Just 2), ("test", Just 3)]`, passing it to my function `validate` would cause it to fail validation - as the order and values of the keys do not match up with the template.

Upon failing validation, I want to generate a new list, which would look like `[("hello", Just 1), ("world", Just 2), ("this", Nothing), ("is", Nothing), ("a", Nothing), ("test", Just 3)]`.

I tried performing this last step using an (incomplete) list comprehension:

```
[(x, y) | x <- template, y <- l]
```

(Obviously, this is missing the step where empty entries would be replaced with `Nothing`s, and works under the assumption that the input is of type `[(String, Maybe Int)]`).

What would be the easiest semantic way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Map String Int` as an intermediate representation of the "list to validate"? Then you could just walk along the template, building a new `[(String, Maybe Int)]` value by filling in the `Int` value when one is associated to the `String` under focus in that map.

Comment: Think you could link me to a docpage for that? I'm still starting out with Haskell, and googling just brings up a bunch of pages about the `Map`, `String`, and `Int` types, separately. Other than that, it sounds like a promising lead.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to *map* a function to your list of strings (which you call "template"), i.e. the function that

- takes a string `xs`,
- returns

  - `(xs, Just n)` if an integer `n` is associated to `xs` in your "list to validate",
  - `(xs, Nothing)` otherwise.

Here is one possible approach:

```hs
import Data.List     ( lookup )
import Control.Monad ( join )

consolidate :: [String] -> [(String, Maybe Int)] -> [(String, Maybe Int)]
consolidate temp l = map (\xs -> (xs, join $ lookup xs l)) temp
```

However, you will get faster lookup if you build a [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map.html) holding the key-value pairs of your association list (the "list to validate"):

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe (maybe)

consolidate :: [String] -> [(String, Maybe Int)] -> [(String, Maybe Int)]
consolidate temp l = map (\cs -> (cs, M.lookup cs $ fromList' l)) temp

fromList' :: Ord a => [(a, Maybe b)] -> M.Map a b
fromList' xs = foldr insertJust M.empty xs

insertJust :: Ord a => (a, Maybe b) -> M.Map a b -> M.Map a b
insertJust (xs, maybeVal) mp = maybe mp (\n -> M.insert xs n mp) maybeVal
```

In GHCi:

```
λ> let myTemplate = ["hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "test"]
λ> let myList = [("hello", Just 1), ("world", Just 2), ("test", Just 3)]
λ> consolidate myTemplate myList 
[("hello",Just 1),("world",Just 2),("this",Nothing),("is",Nothing),("a",Nothing),("test",Just 3)]
```