# Sort list according to a template

Tags: sorting, haskell

How to sort a list (reposition its elements) in Haskell according to another list (the template)? For example I have 2 lists:

```
[1,2,3]
[(2,'b'),(1,'a'),(3,'c')]
```

I want to sort the 2nd list, so that firsts of each its element would correspond to the elements of the 1st list. I.e. I want it to be `[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]`.

I wrote a horribly inelegant implementation:

```
sortMimicking :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortMimicking template xs = filterJust $ r (reverse template) xs []
  where filterJust [] = []
        filterJust (x:xs) = case x of
          Nothing -> filterJust xs
          Just element -> element:filterJust xs
        deleteWith comparison xs = [ x | x <- xs, not $ comparison x ]
        r _ [] acc = acc
        r (t:ts) xs acc = r ts
                          (deleteWith ((==t) . fst) xs)
                          (find ((==t) . fst) xs : acc)
```

It works only with lists of pairs, so I wrote this generalization:

```
sortMimickingBy :: (Eq a) => (b -> a) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
sortMimickingBy c template xs = filterJust $ r (reverse template) xs []
  where filterJust [] = []
        filterJust (x:xs) = case x of
          Nothing -> filterJust xs
          Just element -> element:filterJust xs
        deleteWith comparison xs = [ x | x <- xs, not $ comparison x ]
        r _ [] acc = acc
        r (t:ts) xs acc = r ts
                          (deleteWith ((==t) . c) xs)
                          (find ((==t) . c) xs : acc)
```

I tried to come up with a more elegant function using [`sortWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:sortWith) from [`GHC.Exts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html) module, but to no avail. There's [a similar Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12814667/596361).

Comment: Do you want to sort using the first element in the tuple or use the exact same order as in the initial list , e.g. `sortM [2,3,1] [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]` => `[(2,'b'), (3,'c'), (1,'a')]`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31298466/2541573 for a very similar question.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow `Ord a`, you can do an `O(n log n)` solution instead of the quadratic solution with the linear element lookups. The idea is to remember the original positions of the elements of the template list (by zipping with `[0..]`), then sort multiple times to align the elements and then recover the right order.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sortMimicking :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortMimicking guide xs = map snd $ sortBy (comparing (snd . fst)) $ zip guide' xs'
  where
    guide' = sortBy (comparing fst) $ zip guide [0..]
    xs'    = sortBy (comparing fst) xs
```

Comment: I like the idea given here, but it seems to require that `map fst xs` and `guide` be equal (as bags), which may not be a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Data.List (sortBy, elemIndex)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

mySort :: [Int] -> [(Int,a)] -> [(Int,a)]
mySort as bs = sortBy (comparing go) bs
  where go (a,b) = maybe 0 id (elemIndex a as)
```

Example:

```
ghci> mySort [3,2,1] [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c')]
[(3,'c'),(2,'b'),(1,'a')]
```

Basically `go (a,b)` computes the index of `a` in the first list and `sortBy (comparing go) ...` sorts by comparing `go` on each pair.

Note: It's not very efficient since `elemIndex` scans from the front of the list every time it is called.

Comment: You should use `Data.Map` and `loopup` for better access times