# Algorithm to merge two lists

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to merge two lists of tuples, `x` and `y`. Basically is I have these lists:

```
[("hello", "hi"), ("foo", "baz"), ("this", "that")]

--and

[("foo", "bar"), ("hello", "world"), ("goo", "boo")]

--the result should be

[("hello", "world"), ("foo", "bar"), ("this", "that")]
```

I've written this so far:

```
merge :: (Eq a) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
merge [] _ = []
merge _ [] = []
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | fst x == fst y = (fst y, snd y) : merge xs ys
    | otherwise = (fst x, snd x) : merge xs ys
```

The problem with this solution is that it only merges that are the same index. How can I efficiently iterate over the second list and merge it into the first?

Comment: This is the composition of two relations.  It seems like you are basing the code on a sorted merge, but this is really nothing like merging.  See [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup).  For more efficiency, convert your lists to `Data.Map`s, which is closer to what they are representing.

Comment: Not sure I understand. FYI im a haskell noob. Why should I convert my strucures to `Data.Map`?

Comment: Can you explain just what you mean by "merge"? You gave a small example, but expressing it carefully in words will help.

Comment: @luqui It does not look as composition of relations: there's no `hi` in the second list, for instance. I fail to understand what the general rule is for this "merge".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298466/populating-a-list-of-tuples-in-a-semantic-way

Answer (score 1):

Right now, if the `otherwise` clause doesn’t match, your code discards both `x` and `y`.  It should be trying to merge `x` with the rest of `ys`.  Some hints: `[x]` is a list you can pass to `merge`, and if you can think of a way to divide and conquer the problem, you can concatenate a pair of lists with `++`.

The correct solution is going to involve combining the results of different steps, and when you start doing that, the efficient approach is going to be tail-recursion.

Comment: The fact that the current code is not tail recursive is not a problem at all. It's actually quite efficient. The problem is just that it doesn't do what it should. Haskell's evaluation is lazy, which means you have to reason about efficiency a bit differently.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer, which was about how to make his solution correct, or I just was unclear.  What he wrote *is* in fact tail-recursive; it’s just not correct.  But the correct solution is going to involve divide and conquer.  I’ll move that sentence to the end so it’s less confusing a digression.

Comment: Or actually, I can think of some other approaches that would work equally well.

Comment: It doesnt seem like my code discards both x and y. It discards y only if it does not match x. which is the point of the merge, right?

Comment: Take another look at the last argument on the right-hand side of the `otherwise` case.  Where’s `y`?